# How to add array of objects inside a Map in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want a Map where the keys are unique ids and the value will be an array of objects that correspond to the unique id.
Example data

```
const exampleData = [
{id: 1,
name: "Tony",
},
{id: 2,
name: "Lori"
},
{id: 2,
name: "Pete"
},
{id: 2,
name: "Brandon"
},
];
```

This is what I tried

```
let map = new Map();
filteredArray.map(array => {
  map.set(array.assessmentId, [...map.get(array.assessmentId), array]); 
});
```

Result I want:

```
Map (
[key: 1,
value: [id: 1, Name: Tony],
],
[key:2,
value:[id: 2, Name: Lori],[id: 2, Name: Pete], [id: 2, Name: Brandon]
])
```

Comment: May be good to look at this https://www.consolelog.io/group-by-in-javascript/

Comment: Your desired result is not a Javascript `Map`.

Comment: @connexo I thought I'd use a Map similar to how we use a HashTable to check if the id already exists and add to it. If not I'd add a new id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group the data, you can reduce the items and concatenate each item to an array that is keyed by the `id` property.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Tony", },
  { id: 2, name: "Lori" },
  { id: 2, name: "Pete" },
  { id: 2, name: "Brandon" },
];

const grouped = new Map(Object.entries(data.reduce((result, item) => ({
  ...result,
  [item.id]: [ ...(result[item.id] || []), item ]
}), {})));
  
console.log(...grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Output

```json
{
  "1": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Tony" }
  ],
  "2": [
    { "id": 2, "name": "Lori" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Pete" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Brandon" }
  ]
}
```

Here is a reusable function:

```js
const groupDataByKey = (data, key) =>
  new Map(Object.entries(data.reduce((result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [item[key]]: [ ...(result[item[key]] || []), item ]
  }), {})));
  
const exampleData = [
  { id: 1, name: "Tony", },
  { id: 2, name: "Lori" },
  { id: 2, name: "Pete" },
  { id: 2, name: "Brandon" },
];

console.log(...groupDataByKey(exampleData, 'id'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: OP asked for a `Map`.

Comment: @connexo I just wrapped the return statement with `new Map(Object.entries(...))`